# TFS_ Delete a file without checking out it

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Dear stackoverflower,

Today I need to delete a file in my project without make a check out in TFS, could anyone tell me how to do that?

Say that Dev A had checked in a file X to TFS, and I get X to my computer (my project).

Now for some reason I need to delete X/ get version of X before X was added without checking out X.

And I stuck on how to do that (can't check out it so that others can check out and edit it).

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I have found one way to do that, Using Visual studio GUI:

1. Navigate to file X, right click and choose (Source control)/"Get Specific Version..."
2. In the Get popup, in Version - Type (Alt + T), choose "Date", a date textbox will appear. Choose the datatime before the time file X was added. (To get added time, use "View history" of file X)
3. Click "Get" (Alt + G)
4. File X will be delete in your project without being check out by you in TFS.

Best regard!